# form_for update method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, form-for

On a page I have task listed out. I want to put a form for that task as an update to complete that task. I have the following code as a form_for:

```
<%= form_for :event, :action => :update, :id => event.id do |f| %>
  <%= f.check_box :complete %>
  <%= f.submit 'Complete %>
<% end %>
```

With this code I want it to edit the event with the id in the url and complete the event. What it does it creates a new event instead. Any ideas?

Event Controller:

```
    class EventsController < ApplicationController
  layout 'events', :except => 'edit'
  # GET /events
  # GET /events.json
  def index
    @events = Event.order("events.initials ASC, events.priroty ASC")
    @archived = CompleteEvent.order("complete_events.created_at ASC")


    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @events }
    end
  end

  # GET /events/1
  # GET /events/1.json
  def show
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @event }
    end
  end

  # GET /events/new
  # GET /events/new.json
  def new
    @event = Event.new
    @users = ['BG', 'BD', 'MB', 'AF', 'RA', 'JM']
    @name = ['Brad Garrison', 'Brian Davis', 'Matt Broach', 'Alan McFarland', 'Russell Anderson', 'Jason Milam']

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @event }
    end
  end

  # GET /events/1/edit
  def edit
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    @users = ['BG', 'BD', 'MB', 'AF', 'RA', 'JM']
    @name = ['Brad Garrison', 'Brian Davis', 'Matt Broach', 'Alan McFarland', 'Russell Anderson', 'Jason Milam']

  end

  # POST /events
  # POST /events.json
  def create
    @event = Event.new(params[:event])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save
        user = @event.name 
        Notifier.task_created(user).deliver
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @event, status: :created, location: @event }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /events/1
  # PUT /events/1.json
  def update
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    @save = @event.update_attributes(params[:event])
      @complete = CompleteEvent.new(:initials => @event.initials, :name => @event.name, :event_name => @event.event_name, :complete => @event.complete, :event_description => @event.event_description, :comment => @event.comment)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.update_attributes(params[:event])
        if @event.complete == true
          user = @event.name
          @save
              @complete
              @complete.save
              @event.destroy
          format.html { redirect_to :controller => :events, :action => :index}
          format.json { head :no_content }
            elsif @event.complete == false          
          Notifier.task_updated(user).deliver
          format.html { redirect_to :controller => :events, :action => :index}
          format.json { head :no_content }
            end
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /events/1
  # DELETE /events/1.json
  def destroy
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    @event.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to events_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end


end
```

Comment: post your controller codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was missing was that my form was in a loop. Therefore when I was calling the form_for @event it couldn't see outside of that loop. I had the function take on the variable of event.

```
<% @events.each do |event| %>
  ......
  ......
  <% form_for event do |f| %>
     .....
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In edit.html.erb (or your partial that is rendered in edit.html.erb) use:

```
<%= form_for @event do |f| %>
```

You generally do not need to specify the action, since it is inferred from the URI path, and Rails knows the id for the model object is @event.id.

Comment: When I put <%= form_for @event do |f| %> it throws the following error: undefined method 'model_name' for NilClass:Class. Any ideas?

Comment: In edit.html.erb? In the edit action, it is doing @event = Event.find(params[:id]). Are you certain an event with that ID exists? Does it work with new.html.erb?

Comment: When I put the <%= form_for @event do |f| %> it gives me the following error:

Comment: When I put the <%= form_for @event do |f| %> it gives me the following error: "undefined method 'model_name' for NilClass:Class. But if I put <%= form_for :event, :url => {:action => :update, :id => @event} do |f| %> it doesn't error out until I go to update the field with the checkbox and it gives me the following error: "Called id.for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id". I hope this clears it up a little.

Comment: It's the same error really. Your event is nil. What events do you have in your database? What are their ids? Are you editing one of them, or trying to edit an event that does not exist?